Why NGINX doesn't work with Django project?
I have a Django project that works using setup Django web-server. I want to use nginx and uWSGI. I created a directory in root Django folder called nginx/nginx.conf and nginx/default.conf to set nginx. Ir successfully works at http://localhost:8080 and shows nginx start page (site also starts with uwsgi --http :8000 --module brand_site.wsgi). But when I try http://localhost:8080/blog/corgifume-posts/ it shows 404 Not Found. What's the problem? Why my site doesn't work with nginx?
nginx.conf
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # where my uwsgi_param stores in local machine
    server_tokens off;
    include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/default.conf; 
}

default.conf
server {
    listen 8080; # what port to listen
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; # where to address requests 
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = config/wsgi.py

strict = true  
socket = :8000 
protocol = http

master = true  

no-orphans = true   

die-on-term = true  

lazy-apps = true

processes = 4  

threads = 8   

enable-threads = true  

max-requests = 500

reload-on-rss = 1024

worker-reload-mercy = 60

harakiri = 60
harakiri-verbose = true

vacuum = true

post-buffering = 1048576

buffer-size = 65535

The path to my website: /Users/nnhufg/Desktop/CORGIFUME/brand_site

Don't know the answer, but I used uwsgi_pass in nginx and it worked for me. I was following this tutorial pretty blindly to learn Dockerization ... https://londonappdeveloper.com/deploying-django-with-docker-compose/
